# What is this game with multiplying aliens and random weapons?

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember playing a game with my parents when I was a kid (in the mid 1990s) where you played either as the crew on a ship being invaded by multiplying aliens or as the aliens themselves.

The board was a series of rooms on the ship with the crew-members and weapons strewn all over the place. The part I remember most was that weapons had a random effect (picked from a pile), so you never knew if they would damage the aliens or cause them to multiply until you used one.

The goal of the crew was to escape the ship, and obviously for the aliens it was to kill the crew.

Does anyone know the game I'm talking about, or have I got my games mixed up?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The Awful Green Things From Outer Space](http://www.sjgames.com/awfulgreen/) by [Steve Jackson Games](http://www.sjgames.com/)

Comment: Ah! Of course! Thanks. :) You answered so fast it's too early for me to mark it as accepted...

Comment: I happen to know of its existence because it has been on my 'must try sometime' list for quite some time now. Never played it, but it looks and sounds like a blast!

Comment: It was definitely very disconcerting using a weapon for the first time and not knowing if you were going to get less or a whole lot more trouble from it! Other than being amused by that I'm afraid time has murked any further recommendation than "seemed like fun".

Comment: It's a long-standing personal favourite of mine, mostly because I really like asymmetric games.  (Also, an Awful Green Thing was the first miniature I ever scratchbuilt and painted.  But I never got round to making the crew.)  But don't play if you hate random factors; the balance between crew and Green Things can depend heavily on the randomised starting position, and on whether the crew has a good area-effect weapon available - if the Comm Beamer or Fire Extinguisher turn out do heavily lethal or shrink damage, the crew's in a *much* better position than if they don't.

Comment: @StuartPegg time to come back and hit the Accept button!

Comment: @aramis: Why would I unaccept it?

Comment: I was goign to say that it clearly wasn't but sounded a lot like Snits -- which is also by Tom Wham.